# Анимация текста при скроллинге

Tags: jquery, анимация, css-animation, прокрутка

При скроллинге текст скрыт с помощью `css`-свойства `transform:translateX(-100%)` (можно и с помощью другого способа).
Нужно чтобы при скролле вниз текст выезжал, а при скролле вверх текст заезжал обратно.
Получается нужно позицию текста привязать к скроллу.
Подскажите, как это правильно сделать?

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e){
 var offsetTop = $(window).scrollTop()
  console.log('offsetTop - '+offsetTop);
})
$('span').waypoint({
  handler: function(direction) {
    var $el = $(this.element);
    $el.addClass('visibled');
    console.log('direction '+direction);
    
  },
  offset: '90%'
})
```

```css
section{
  height: 400px;
  border:1px solid;
}
span{
  transform:translateX(-100%);
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section class="section1">section1</section>
<section class="section2"><span>section2</span></section>
<section class="section3"><span>section3</span></section>
<section class="section4"><span>section4</span></section>
<section class="section5"><span>section5</span></section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0zqmLdb1/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MoloF/dq08egjL/28/)

### Вариант анимации при каждом успешном значении `isIntersecting`

```js
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('section');

const options = {
 threshold: 0.7
};

const callback = (entries, observer) => {
 entries.forEach(entry => {
  const span = entry.target.querySelector('span');
  const method = entry.isIntersecting ? 'add' : 'remove';
  span.classList[method]('focus');
 });
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

targets.forEach(target => observer.observe(target));
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 margin-bottom: 10%;
}
section:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }

.text-wrapper {
 overflow: hidden;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: Arial;
}

.text-wrapper span {
 transition: all 1s;
 display: block;
}

.text-wrapper.visibility span { visibility: hidden; }
.text-wrapper.translateX span { transform: translateX(-100%); }
.text-wrapper.translateY span { transform: translateY(100%); }
.text-wrapper.translateX.invert span { transform: translateX(100%); }
.text-wrapper.translateY.invert span { transform: translateY(-100%); }
.text-wrapper.opacity span { opacity: 0; }

.text-wrapper.visibility span.focus { visibility: visible; }
.text-wrapper.translateX span.focus { transform: translateX(0); }
.text-wrapper.translateY span.focus { transform: translateY(0); }
.text-wrapper.opacity span.focus { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <section>
  <div class="text-wrapper visibility">
   <span>Анимация текста при скроллинге</span>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="text-wrapper translateX">
   <span>Анимация текста при скроллинге</span>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="text-wrapper translateX invert">
   <span>Анимация текста при скроллинге</span>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="text-wrapper translateY invert">
   <span>Анимация текста при скроллинге</span>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="text-wrapper translateY">
   <span>Анимация текста при скроллинге</span>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="text-wrapper opacity">
   <span>Анимация текста при скроллинге</span>
  </div>
 </section>
</div>
```

---

### Вариант анимации в одном направлении один раз.

Добавил удаление слежки после того как элемент был показан на экране.

```js
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('section');

const options = {
 threshold: 0.7
};

const callback = entries => {
 entries.forEach(entry => {
  if (entry.isIntersecting) {
   observer.unobserve(entry.target);
   const span = entry.target.querySelector('span');
   span.classList.add('focus');
  }
 });
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

targets.forEach(target => observer.observe(target));
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 margin-bottom: 10%;
}
section:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }

.text-wrapper {
 overflow: hidden;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: Arial;
}

.text-wrapper span {
 transition: all 1s;
 display: block;
}

.text-wrapper.visibility span { visibility: hidden; }
.text-wrapper.translateX span { transform: translateX(-100%); }
.text-wrapper.translateY span { transform: translateY(100%); }
.text-wrapper.translateX.invert span { transform: translateX(100%); }
.text-wrapper.translateY.invert span { transform: translateY(-100%); }
.text-wrapper.opacity span { opacity: 0; }

.text-wrapper.visibility span.focus { visibility: visible; }
.text-wrapper.translateX span.focus { transform: translateX(0); }
.text-wrapper.translateY span.focus { transform: translateY(0); }
.text-wrapper.opacity span.focus { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <section>
  <div class="text-wrapper visibility">
   <span>Анимация текста при скроллинге</span>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="text-wrapper translateX">
   <span>Анимация текста при скроллинге</span>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="text-wrapper translateX invert">
   <span>Анимация текста при скроллинге</span>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="text-wrapper translateY invert">
   <span>Анимация текста при скроллинге</span>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="text-wrapper translateY">
   <span>Анимация текста при скроллинге</span>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="text-wrapper opacity">
   <span>Анимация текста при скроллинге</span>
  </div>
 </section>
</div>
```

Comment: я не понял что такое observer

Comment: @MaximLensky [вот вам документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: я видел это - но почитаю  - внимательно - thank you

Comment: @Sevastopol' , я сторонник как раз наоборот, чтобы анимация проигрывалась при первом прохождении, а дальше замирала на месте и "плавала". Просто с верху в низ анимация может красиво смотреться, но наоборот может выглядеть не очень, в том и проблема

Comment: @Sevastopol' добавил второй вариант анимации!

Answer (score 6):

StackOverflow - это огромная уникальная база данных. Можно воспользоваться поиском и найти [массу разнообразных примеров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1109434/31280), или взять что-то [похожее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1078595/31280) и доработать код под себя. Вот пример:

```js
var parallax = document.querySelector('.parallax');
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  var {
    top,
    bottom
  } = parallax.getBoundingClientRect();
  var size = 0;
  if (top < 0 && bottom > window.innerHeight) size = Math.round(-top / (parallax.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) * 100);
  if (bottom < window.innerHeight) size = 100;
  document.querySelector('span').style.left = `${size}px`;
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header,
.footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100vh;
}

.parallax {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: beige;
  height: 2000px;
}

span {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  line-height: 2px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="parallax"><span>Parallax</span></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: какая любовь между между jquery и  javascript :))

Comment: @Sevastopol' скорее всего Максим имел ввиду ваше скрещивание чистого JS и jQuery. В вашем случае можно было вообще убрать jQuery и мало что изменится :^