# Анимация во время скролинга страницы на JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

Помоги пожалуйста сделать анимацию во время скролинга страницы. Тоесть мне нужна анимация как на [сайте](https://www.oneplus.com/ru/8?from=head) (Второй блок где `Fluid дисплей 90 Гц...`  и т.д.)
Как реализовать такое?

```css
.li_spec {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li_spec">Трассировка лучей</li>
  <li class="li_spec">Поддержка телевизоров с разрешением 4К</li>
  <li class="li_spec">До 120 кадров в секунду с поддержкой частоты вывода 120 Гц.</li>
  <li class="li_spec">Технология HDR</li>
  <li class="li_spec">Поддержка разрешения 8K</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vigenhovhannisian/tafnc7qo/19/

Comment: Это не то. Нужно чтобы я сам прокрутил образно страницу на 5% текст выехал из за экрана на 5 %

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Анимация текста при скроллинге](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110108/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b5)

Comment: @MaximLensky Немного не то

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например с использованием библиотеки [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr).

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#anchor'),
    els = el.querySelectorAll('.li_spec'),
    elp = el.getBoundingClientRect();

els.forEach(function (e,i) {
    e.setAttribute('data-anchor-target', '#anchor');
  e.setAttribute('data-50p-top', 'transform:translateX(100%);opacity:0;');
  e.setAttribute('data-'+Math.floor(40-(10*i))+'p-top', 'transform:translateX(0%);opacity:1;');
});

skrollr.init();
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}
section {display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;}
#anchor {background: black; color: white;}
ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; text-align: center;}
ul > li {font-size: 100%;}
ul > li:not(:last-child) {margin-bottom: 1.5em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js"></script>

<section>листай вниз</section>

<section id="anchor">
  <ul>
    <li class="li_spec">Трассировка лучей</li>
    <li class="li_spec">Поддержка телевизоров с разрешением 4К</li>
    <li class="li_spec">До 120 кадров в секунду с поддержкой частоты вывода 120 Гц.</li>
    <li class="li_spec">Технология HDR</li>
    <li class="li_spec">Поддержка разрешения 8K</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

**UPD**: переписал под **[relative mode](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#relative-mode-or-viewport-mode)**, теперь это стало чуть проще и адаптивно.

Comment: на весь экран не работает ?

Comment: @MaximLensky, теперь да)

Comment: @De.Minov спасибо это как раз то что мне нужно.

Comment: @Sevastopol', добрый день. Можно долго спорить насчёт этого) Мне она показалась подходящей и простой.

Answer (score 3):

Если мы далеки от javascript то Вам как и мне приходят на помощь библиотеки, в этом примере покажу [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) которая проста до безумия и выполнит вашу задачу на 100%

> Смотреть на весь экран

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.dummy {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
}

.flex {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text p {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: 0.34s linear;
}

p.focus {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="dummy"></div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="text">
    <p data-aos="fade-left">Fluid дисплей 90 Гц</p>
    <p data-aos="fade-left">Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ 865 with 5G</p>
    <p data-aos="fade-left">Slim and Sleek Curved Design</p>
    <p data-aos="fade-left">48 MP Triple Camera</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script>
  AOS.init();
</script>
```